# Removing blank lines from an all text Google DOC 2

Tags: line, google-docs, paragraph, remove-if

I have an all text Google Doc but it have a lot of places where there are more than 1 blank line/paragraph in a row. I have tried the code below but it stops at "line.removeFromParent()". I would like to remove any extra blank lines leaving only one in each place of a group of them. The code that I tried is:

```
function removeEmptyLines() {
  const s = SlidesApp.getActivePresentation();
  let docname = s.getName();
  let doc = DocumentApp.create("Notes - " + docname);
 
  Logger.log("Before:\n", doc.getBody().getText());  
  
  var paragraphs = doc.getBody().getParagraphs();
  // Iterating from the last paragraph to the first
  for (var i=paragraphs.length-1; i>=0; i--){
    var line = paragraphs[i];
    if ( ! line.getText().trim() ) {
      // Paragraph (line) is empty, remove it
      line.removeFromParent()
      Logger.log("Removed: ", i);
    }
  }
  Logger.log("After:\n", doc.getBody().getText());
}
```

---

I also tried the following it ran but it did not work:

```
const s = SlidesApp.getActivePresentation();
 let docname = s.getName();
 let doc = DocumentApp.create("Notes - " + docname);
 let docId = doc.getId();
 var doc2 = DocumentApp.openById(docId);
 var body3 = doc2.getBody() var paras = body3.getParagraphs();
 var i = 0;
 for (var i = 0; i < paras.length;
 i++) { if (paras[i].getText() === ""){ paras[i].removeFromParent()
 }
 }
```

Comment: "but it stops at" => **WHY**  Does it show an error? Please add this error (in text format) to this question using [edit].

Comment: Please do not post code in a comment, it will be unreadable/unformatted, use [edit] to  improve your question.

Comment: The right debugger panel pops up and the "line.removeFromParent()" is highlighted.

Comment: The error message is --{ [Exception: Can't remove the last paragraph in a document section.] name: 'Exception' }

Comment: Well that seems to be a pretty obvious error message. Is you document empty?

Comment: No, it has 30 pages of text. It is being made and populated by code in the same function.  I also closed and saved it and then opened it before running this program., I replaced docId with the actual ID of the previous filled out file that I saved. same result.

Comment: Change the for loop to: `for (var i=paragraphs.length-2; i>=0; i--){`, but I am clueless as to why this works...   (Just changed my first Google Apps SCript.... )

Comment: Only deletes all but 2 blank lines in the last block. All other blocks of blank lines are untouched

Comment: Is a `block` the same as a paragraph?  The macro loops over paragraphs.

Comment: I discovered that when the document was made it was made a one paragraph and that is why the program does not find blank lines. I will try to fix that.